# Function to determine a most profitable store from a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

I have to create a MySQL function that receives an index and returns the name of the store in that index ordered by profit. How do I set up the function?

This is the query I have done to order the Store based on profit, which is the total sum of items sold times the quantity of the inventory.

```
    SELECT name, (SUM(price * quantity)) AS TotalPrice
    FROM Items NATURAL JOIN Inventory
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY (TotalPrice) DESC;
```

Schema:
Inventory(name: String, item: String, quantity: integer )
Items(item: String, brand: String, price:double )
The error: used Select statement has a different number of columns.

I should be able to return the nth most profitable store. The MySQL command I have functions to create a view in order, but I do not know how to return the index of the ordered table. This is not homework, just review for an exam.

Comment: Profit is not price times quantity.  That would be gross revenue.

Comment: Well, the result given by this query is the desired result, I need to find the most profitable store, profit based on the schema, not on actual definition, would be the SUM(price * quantity of each item on each store. Just wanted to create a function that returns the nth most profitable, but stuck on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a Procedure, just not a Function that gives me the result that I wanted with the following code:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE m2(IN N INTEGER)
BEGIN
SELECT name, (SUM(price * quantity)) AS Total_Profit
FROM Items JOIN
Inventory
USING (item)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY Total_Profit DESC
LIMIT N, 1;
END |
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the nth item in the list using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT name, (SUM(price * quantity)) AS TotalPrice
FROM Items JOIN
     Inventory
     USING (item)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY TotalPrice DESC
OFFSET <n - 1> LIMIT 1
```

So, for the 3rd item, it would be:

```
OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1
```

Note that I removed the `NATURAL JOIN`.  I recommend never using `NATURAL JOIN`s because the code does not show the `JOIN` keys (and so is prone to errors) and because they do not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.

Comment: Ok Awesome, thank you that does make more sense. When creating a function, how would I go about it:
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION mostProfit(n INT(10))
BEGIN
SELECT name, (SUM(price * quantity)) AS TotalPrice
FROM Items JOIN
     Inventory
     USING (item)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY TotalPrice DESC
LIMIT 1, n;
END //